# Storing keyboard Input in x64 assembly (Mac OS/X)

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I have been trying for some time now to get a number from a keyboard and comparing it with a value on the stack.  If it is correct it will print "Hello World!" and if incorrect, it should print out "Nope!". However, what happens now is no matter the input "jne" is called, nope is printed, and segfault.  Perhaps one of you could lend a hand.

```
.section __DATA,__data
    str:
      .asciz "Hello world!\n"

sto:
     .asciz "Nope!\n"

.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _main
_main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp,%rbp
    sub $0x20, %rsp
    movl $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
    movl $0x2, -0x8(%rbp)

    movl $0x2000003, %eax
    mov $0, %edi
    subq $0x4, %rsi
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    syscall

    cmp -0x8(%rbp), %edx
    je L1
    jne L2
    xor %rbx, %rbx
    xor %rax, %rax
    movl $0x2000001, %eax          
    syscall

L1:
    xor %rax, %rax
    movl $0x2000004, %eax         
    movl $1, %edi                 
    movq str@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi 
    movq $14, %rdx               
    syscall
    ret

L2:
    xor %eax, %eax
    movl $0x2000004, %eax          
    movl $1, %edi                   
    movq sto@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi   
    movq $6, %rdx                 
    syscall
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with this [OS/X Syscall tutorial](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/) (The 64-bit part in your case). It is written for NASM syntax but the important information is the text and links  for the *SYSCALL* calling convention. The *SYSCALL* table is found on this [Apple webpage](http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master). Additional information on the standard calling  convention for 64-bit OS/X can be found in the [System V 64-bit ABI](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

Of importance for *SYSCALL* convention:

> - arguments are passed in order via these registers rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8 and r9
> - syscall number in the rax register
> - the call is done via the **syscall** instruction
> - what OS X contributes to the mix is that you have to add 0x20000000 to the syscall number (still have to figure out why)

You have many issues with with your `sys_read` system call. The *SYSCALL* table says this:

> ```
> 3 AUE_NULL    ALL { user_ssize_t read(int fd, user_addr_t cbuf, user_size_t nbyte); }
> ```

So given the calling convention, `int fd` is in *RDI*, `user_addr_t cbuf` (pointer to character buffer to hold return data) is in *RSI*, and `user_size_t nbyte` (maximum bytes buffer can contain) is in *RDX*.

Your program seg faulted on the `ret` because you didn't have proper function epilogue to match the function prologue at the top:

```
push %rbp                 #
mov  %rsp,%rbp            # Function prologue
```

You need to do the reverse at the bottom, set the result code in *RAX* and then do the `ret`. Something like:

```
mov %rbp,%rsp             # \ Function epilogue
pop %rbp                  # /
xor %eax, %eax            # Return value = 0
ret                       # Return to C runtime which will exit
                          #     gracefully and return to OS
```

I did other minor cleanup, but tried to keep the structure of the code similar. You will have to learn more assembly to better understand the code that sets up *RSI* with the address for `sys_read` *SYSCALL* . You should try to find a good tutorial/book on x86-64 assembly language programming in general. Writing a primer on that subject is beyond the scope of this answer.

Code that might be closer to what you were looking for that takes the above into account:

```
.section __DATA,__data
str:
    .asciz "Hello world!\n"

sto:
    .asciz "Nope!\n"

.section __TEXT,__text

.globl _main
_main:
    push %rbp                 #
    mov  %rsp,%rbp            # Function prologue

    sub  $0x20, %rsp          # Allocate 32 bytes of space on stack
                              #     for temp local variables

    movl $0x2, -4(%rbp)       # Number for comparison

                              # 16-bytes from -20(%rbp) to -5(%rbp)
                              #     for char input buffer
    movl $0x2000003, %eax
    mov $0, %edi              # 0 for STDIN
    lea -20(%rbp), %rsi       # Address of temporary buffer on stack
    mov $16, %edx             # Read 16 character maximum
    syscall

    movb (%rsi), %r10b        # RSI = pointer to buffer on stack
                              # get first byte
    subb $48, %r10b           # Convert first character to number 0-9
    cmpb -4(%rbp), %r10b      # Did we find magic number (2)?
    jne L2                    #     If No exit with error message

L1:                           # If the magic number matched print
                              #     Hello World
    xor %rax, %rax
    movl $0x2000004, %eax
    movl $1, %edi
    movq str@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    movq $14, %rdx
    syscall
    jmp L0                    # Jump to exit code

L2:                           # Print "Nope"
    xor %eax, %eax
    movl $0x2000004, %eax
    movl $1, %edi
    movq sto@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    movq $6, %rdx
    syscall

L0:                           # Code to exit main
    mov %rbp,%rsp             # \ Function epilogue
    pop %rbp                  # /
    xor %eax, %eax            # Return value = 0
    ret                       # Return to C runtime which will exit
                              #     gracefully and return to OS
```